# Solution to archive and search PDF files on a NAS

Tags: windows-7, pdf, network-shares, archiving, file-search

In my company we have a lot of customer information saved in .pdf files which are stored on a QNAP NAS.

I want to be able to do a quick search for information inside the .pdf, like Contract Numbers or similar. What could I do to index this information/PDFs, or just to make the search quick?

Is there a way to index it in Windows? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but wouldn't Windows search index PDFs already?

Comment: I don't think so! Just if they are on your local file system.. But that's the problem, since i didn't find out how to index files/folders in the network.

Comment: Ah, [thought so](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-do-i-have-windows-search-index-files-on-a/4f1e1964-9dbb-4136-af3c-32e7aecdf004) — "Unfortunately, indexing of network drives is no longer an available feature in Windows 7."

Comment: Alright, so maybe Windows Search Server is a solution.. But i don't have a server, just a qnap that is running the whole time, so where would i install it?

Comment: OOC: Do you know any programming languages?